# Why is Git ignoring my Help file that ends with .chm?

Tags: git, bash

I'm running on Windows 8.1 x64, using Git Bash, developing in C# and using GitHub for my repository.

I created a help-file, MyHelp.chm, and placed it within it's own directory (Help). When I enter..
$ git status

I see my .cs source-code files in various directories, but I don't see the Help directory that I created, nor the MyHelp.chm file that is in that directory. Entering..
$ git add Help/MyHelp.chm
-does not seem to result in any error-message, but it does not seem to do anything. When I enter
$ git status
again, I still don't see MyHelp.chm in the list to be committed.

I checked the various .gitignore locations - I don't see anything that should impact a .chm file!

Comment: have you tried `git ls-files -v | grep MyHelp.chm`   if you've added it properly,you should see: 'H Help/MyHelp.chm' . If it says anything else its probably being skipped or ignored. If nothing appears, then you haven't added it properly

Comment: did you "git add" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sequence of commands on a fresh repository:

```
> git init so
  Initialized empty Git repository in /path/so/.git/
> cd so
> mkdir Help
> touch Help/MyHelp.chm
> git status
  On branch master

  Initial commit

  Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

      Help/

  nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
> git add Help/MyHelp.chm
> git status
  On branch master

  Initial commit

  Changes to be committed:
    (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

      new file:   Help/MyHelp.chm
>
```

Anything unusual in the workflow you have done so far?

You checked for `.gitignore` in "various locations". Would that be that some other location to check?

PS: The check is on a shell command line, so there may be more specifics on your version.

Comment: @JamesWHurst, Could you comment on what part of my answer did help you solve the problem? I appreciate being marked as correct answer, but it would be helpful if this SO thread could really pin point problem and solution.